# Migration to GA4

Tags: laravel, google-analytics-4

I Have migrated my Google Analytics UA properties to Google Analytics GA4 properties  for UA properties we are using Spatie/analytics library which uses Google Analytics Reporting API v4 now that my properties are migrated to GA4 and have to migrate the reporting API as the one we are using will not support GA4  . I wanted to know how can i maintain configuration for both(UA reporting and GA4 reporting) in my analytics.php  file

Could not Find anything related to this

Comment: UA Reporting is going away in july. You cant get anyfurther data from July onwards. Better to keep GA4

Comment: Right just went through the documentation